# ng-model value are not updated after edit the input value in AnguarJs?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

[image]I have to Create the basic CRUD application in which user is edit the product detail, but in my case input value is filled but after edit the value,edited value are not show in the controller how to fix this problem

```js
//editProductDetail function for edit the product detail
 $scope.editProductObj = [];
  $scope.editProductDetail = function(productObject) {
  $scope.editProductObj  = productObject;
 }
  

//call  udpateProductDetailc function for update the detail
$scope.item          = {};
$scope.getProductKey = [];
$scope.udpateProductDetail = function(index, productObject) {
  var data = {
    productId     : $scope.item.pid,
    productName   : $scope.item.pname,
    brandName     : $scope.item.bname,
    productPrice  : Number($scope.item.price)
   }

  $scope.getProductKey  = productObject.key;
  var db     = firebase.database();
  var sellerProduct = db.ref("sellerProduct"); 
  }
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="list in productArray">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa fa-group" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('editProduct').style.display='block'"       ng-click="editProductDetail(list)">
   </a>
   <div>
   
<div class="w3-container"> 
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="w3-container">
          <label>Enter Prduct Id</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.pid"
          value="{{editProductObj.productId}}"><br>
           <label>Enter Brand Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.bname"
          value="{{editProductObj.brandName}}"><br>
           <label>Enter Product Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.pname"
            value="{{editProductObj.productName}}"><br>
           <label>Enter Product Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="text"  ng-model="item.price"
          value="{{editProductObj.productPrice}}"><br>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="w3-btn w3-blue" ng-model="wholeItem"
    ng-click="udpateProductDetail($index, editProductObj)">Udpate
</div>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the "$scope.item" like this:

```
$scope.item = {pid: "",bname:"",pname:"",price:""};
```

Answer (score 0):

What is changed in `input` when you change content is `ng-model`. You don't need to use `value` (`ng-value`)

So your HTML should look like:

```
<div class=""> 
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="w3-container">
          <label>Enter Prduct Id</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.pid"><br>
           <label>Enter Brand Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.bname"><br>
           <label>Enter Product Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="text" ng-model="item.pname"><br>
           <label>Enter Product Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="text"  ng-model="item.price"><br>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sir why i don't need value?i am using value for filled the  specific product detail in the input field after click the function?

Comment: @kapilsoni can you explain what you want to do? what is `item` and what is `editProductObj `?

Comment: Sir i have to udpate the produt detail of the selected product.here, 'editProductObj' is a selected product object it will be get from his editProductObj  function and item is user for the get the input.sir please check my updated fiddle?

Comment: @kapilsoni What is the structure of `productObject `? is it should be same as `item`?

Comment: productObject  :-User click on the product Icon after then model is open in which show whole product detail is get and hold the  product detail into the  productObject? no sir both are not same, item will be user for get the input field value?